# How to install Hadoop on M1 Mac

Tags: hadoop

I followed serveral tuitorial and everytime I start Hadoop will have these

```
feiyechen@FEIYEdeMac-mini ~ % start-all.sh
WARNING: Attempting to start all Apache Hadoop daemons as feiyechen in 10 seconds.
WARNING: This is not a recommended production deployment configuration.
WARNING: Use CTRL-C to abort.
Starting namenodes on [localhost]
Starting datanodes
localhost: datanode is running as process 55832.  Stop it first and ensure /tmp/hadoop-feiyechen-datanode.pid file is empty before retry.
Starting secondary namenodes [FEIYEdeMac-mini.local]
FEIYEdeMac-mini.local: secondarynamenode is running as process 55966.  Stop it first and ensure /tmp/hadoop-feiyechen-secondarynamenode.pid file is empty before retry.
2022-01-28 20:35:24,311 WARN util.NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
Starting resourcemanager
Starting nodemanagers
feiyechen@FEIYEdeMac-mini ~ % jps
55832 DataNode
57838 Jps
55966 SecondaryNameNode
57247 NameNode
```

Tutorial said should got these after run jps

[image]

I only have 4 items: DataNode, Jps, SecondaryNameNode, NameNode. Is that mean I failed?

Comment: Did you find any solution? Were you getting 
`java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Could not load library. Reasons: [no leveldbjni64-1.8 in java.library.path, no leveldbjni-1.8 in java.library.path, no leveldbjni in java.library.path (fat file, but missing compatible architecture (have 'x86_64,i386', need 'arm64e'))]` ?

Answer (score 0):

It means you have a running HDFS installation, but not YARN.

You should be able to run `start-yarn.sh` separately if you want the `ResourceManger` + `NodeManager`

Otherwise, there are log files created for both the YARN processes that would include information about why they are failing.